# HTML5 offline support for JSR 286 portlets

Tags: java, html5-appcache, spring-portlet-mvc

I want my application developed using spring portlets to work when it is not connected to a network. I have used the HTML5 offline (using appcache) feature and developed a sample servlet and it is working perfectly fine.

The same is not working in portlets.

Is there any limitation with portlet-based applications? I searched the Web but could not find  much information on this.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem why it was not working for portlets.
Portal server adds "Cache-Control: no cache" in http header which prevents caching even though appcache is available.